# MySQL email address encryption

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

How to encrypt email address in MySQL? The column type is Char(255). MySQL version 5.5.33.
The email address should be able to retrieve back to plain text, since it will be used in the application.

I want to store the email address in encrypted form in char(255) column in MySQL database.

The `AES_ENCYPT()` function do not allow char(255) data type. I can change the data type provided performance is not reduced.  Which is the best way to encrypt and store email address in MySQL?

Comment: The question is why you need to encrypt the email addresses?

Comment: There are heaps of functions you can choose. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have another issue here. AES_ENCRYPT definitely can take a CHAR(n) datatype as a parameter. Tested on 5.5.29.

Do you get a specific error message?